# I am making a python tkinter calculator and can't get the value to change

Tags: python, button, tkinter, calculator

I am making a calculator in python using Tkinter and I can't  get the button to change the text on the label. Thank you in advance.

```
calc = Tk()
calc.title("Calculator")
calc.configure(bg='gray')


def nu1():
    numbers == '1'

numbers = '0'

screen = Label(calc, text=numbers)
screen.grid(row=0, column=0)

no1 = Button(calc, text='1', command=nu1)
no1.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numbers == '1'` tests if `numbers` equals the '1' string, and then it throws the result away. I suspect you meant to do

```
numbers = '1'
```

but that still won't work. Firstly, that assignment creates a new `numbers` that's local to the `nu1` function, it has nothing to do with your global `numbers`. Secondly, that's not how to change the text of a Label: you need to call its `configure` method, which can be shortened to `config`. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk 

calc = tk.Tk()
calc.title("Calculator")
calc.geometry('200x200')

def nu1():
    screen.config(text='1')

numbers = '0'

screen = tk.Label(calc, text=numbers)
screen.grid(row=0, column=0)

no1 = tk.Button(calc, text='1', command=nu1)
no1.grid(row=0, column=2)

calc.mainloop()
```

That solves your immediate problem. However, you will find that this isn't adequate to build a calculator.